# import from file data error in Python

Tags: python

I'm having some issues importing data from file in Python. I am quite new to Python, so my error is probably quite simple.

I am reading in 3 column, tab-delimited text files with no headers. I am creating 3 instances of the data file using three different datafiles.

I can see that each object is referencing a different memory location, so they are separate.

When I look at the data stored in each instance, each instance has the same contents, consisting of the three datafiles appended to each other.

What have I done wrong?

The class to read in the data is:

```
class Minimal:

    def __init__(self, data=[]):
        self.data = data

    def readFile(self, filename):
        f = open(filename, 'r')

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            #creates a list of angle, intensity and error and appends it to the diffraction pattern
            self.data.append( [float(columns[0]), float(columns[1]), float(columns[2])] )
        f.close()

    def printData(self):
        for dataPoint in self.data:
            print str(dataPoint)
```

The datafiles look like:

```
1   4   2
2   5   2.3
3   4   2
4   6   2.5
5   8   5
6   10  3
```

The program I am using to actually create the instances of Minimal is:

```
from minimal import Minimal

d1 = Minimal()
d1.readFile("data1.xye")

d2 = Minimal()
d2.readFile("data2.xye")

d3 = Minimal()
d3.readFile("data3.xye")


print "Data1"
print d1
d1.printData()

print "\nData2"
print d2
d2.printData()

print "\nData3"
print d3
d3.printData()
```

The output is:

```
Data1
<minimal.Minimal instance at 0x016A35F8>
[1.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[2.0, 5.0, 2.3]
[3.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[4.0, 6.0, 2.5]
[5.0, 8.0, 5.0]
[6.0, 10.0, 3.0]
[2.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[3.0, 5.0, 2.3]
[4.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[5.0, 6.0, 2.5]
[6.0, 8.0, 5.0]
[7.0, 10.0, 3.0]
[3.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 2.3]
[5.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[6.0, 6.0, 2.5]
[7.0, 8.0, 5.0]
[8.0, 10.0, 3.0]

Data2
<minimal.Minimal instance at 0x016A3620>
[1.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[2.0, 5.0, 2.3]
[3.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[4.0, 6.0, 2.5]
[5.0, 8.0, 5.0]
[6.0, 10.0, 3.0]
[2.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[3.0, 5.0, 2.3]
[4.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[5.0, 6.0, 2.5]
[6.0, 8.0, 5.0]
[7.0, 10.0, 3.0]
[3.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 2.3]
[5.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[6.0, 6.0, 2.5]
[7.0, 8.0, 5.0]
[8.0, 10.0, 3.0]

Data3
<minimal.Minimal instance at 0x016A3648>
[1.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[2.0, 5.0, 2.3]
[3.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[4.0, 6.0, 2.5]
[5.0, 8.0, 5.0]
[6.0, 10.0, 3.0]
[2.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[3.0, 5.0, 2.3]
[4.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[5.0, 6.0, 2.5]
[6.0, 8.0, 5.0]
[7.0, 10.0, 3.0]
[3.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 2.3]
[5.0, 4.0, 2.0]
[6.0, 6.0, 2.5]
[7.0, 8.0, 5.0]
[8.0, 10.0, 3.0]

Tool completed successfully
```

Comment: `def __init__(self, data=[]):` <- The curse of the [mutable default argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) strikes again!

Comment: Can you post the contents of the 3 files?  It would be very helpful.

Comment: @MarioRossi : The files have the same 2nd and 3rd columns. The 1st columns start with 1, 2 or 3 and go up in steps of 1 for 6 rows

Comment: Wouldn't the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module be appropriate for parsing the file? Doesn't solve the problem, but it would be cleaner code, I think.

Comment: @jpmc26 quite possibly, but I am trying to teach myself Python, so I did it this way, and the files aren't that complex...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default value `data` is evaluated only once; `data` attributes of Minimal instances reference the same list.

```
>>> class Minimal:
...     def __init__(self, data=[]):
...         self.data = data
... 
>>> a1 = Minimal()
>>> a2 = Minimal()
>>> a1.data is a2.data
True
```

Replace as follow:

```
>>> class Minimal:
...     def __init__(self, data=None):
...         self.data = data or []
... 
>>> a1 = Minimal()
>>> a2 = Minimal()
>>> a1.data is a2.data
False
```

See [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: Well stuff me. I thought that data would be shared only if it was defined outside of the __init__

Comment: It *is* defined outside of the init!  Default values are evaluated on function *definition*, not on function invocation.  The explanation is too long for a comment so I will add an answer.

Comment: I just realized that the root of the problem is **not** that the "`data` attribute is shared by all instance".  This would make very little sense, in fact.  The root cause is that its **default value in __init__** is shared.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
def d():
   print("d() invoked")
   return 1

def f(p=d())
   pass

print"("Start")
f()
f()
```

It prints

```
d() invoked
Start
```

Not

```
Start
d() invoked
d() invoked
```

Why?  Because default arguments are computed on **function definition** (and stored in some kind of internal global for reuse every subsequent time they are needed).  They are **not** computed on each **function invocation**.

In other words, they behave more or less like:

```
_f_p_default= d()
def f(p)
   if p is None: p= _f_p_default
   pass
```

Make the above substitution in your code, and you will understand the problem immediately.

The correct form for your code was already provided by @falsetru .  I'm just trying to explain the rationale.

Comment: Thanks for that. My background is all in Java, so the different paradigms are still conflicting with me. (I still feel dirty not giving my variables a type on definition!).

Comment: @masher You are obviously no beginner. That's why I wanted to explain things a bit deeper. I can't wait optional static type checking is added to Python, either. Not only because I miss it, but because it's very useful, especially in larger scale applications.